# Do I need php-fpm to serve MongoDB persistent connections

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

I have an outdated apache/php_mod configuration on my servers. Will PHP persist connections as in documentation without having php-fpm or it is required?

Comment: PHP mod doesn't use php-fpm, so what is the connection here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP MongoDB driver is often used with [PHP-FPM](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) on nginx.
However, you do not need PHP-FPM on Apache to [persist connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.connection-handling.php).

Anyways, make sure to use a [MongoDB/Driver version 1.2 or newer or you may not gain any performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196509/persistent-connections-with-new-mongo-php-driver).

Also, take a look at the MongoDB documentation of [compatible PHP drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/).